# Firefox Add-on SDK: Disable same origin policy for contentScripts?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to write a firefox extension by FF add-on SDK and I need to have access from my contentScript to all iframes of different origins. I know that using [cross-domain-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts) we can allow access to the contents of specific origins, but it dose not allow to define wildcard urls so it is not possible to have a contentScript which has access to all iframes of a page. Is there a way to have access to all the frames of a page from the  contentScript attached to the top window?